Download files in MAUI iOS Fails to Download Content
I've tried to implement the solution given on Download files in MAUI iOS WebView almost exactly, but the resulting file contents only contain the name of the file, not the expected document contents.
Is there some extra code needed for either the NSUrlSessionCreateDownloadTask(url) in the StartDownload() method, or is there more code needed in the MyDownloadDelegate class?
Maybe there is another direction I can take altogether?

Have you checked the source URL if it is correct? You may also refer to this thread, WebView on iOS cann't download file

Thanks for you response, Liqun. The source URL works correctly on Android, plus I can download directly on a browser with the same source URL. Thanks also for the reference link, however, it has pretty much the same code I am already using.

Upon further investigation, I see that the system is unable to display the file contents as a PDF, which is why all I see is the file name. When I look at the contents, I see the login page for the site from which I am trying to download the PDF. It appears that even though I am logged into the site in the webview, my session isn't being passed in the request (as part of the cookie). When the app tries to access the file, it is being redirected to the login page and that html is being downloaded, instead.

The code provided in the link above doesn't discuss how to handle a cookie or a session. Is there any code example that does that?

Here is a related issue on GitHub, WebView Cookies not working, which is tagged as fixed now

The WebView object has the cookie information, or it would not be possible to navigate to the server pages. It appears that I must manually retrieve the cookie from the WebView object. Then I must inject that into the request object and re-send it. The problem is that the documentation is cryptic, and any sample code I can find is in objective C or some language other than C# with Maui. Is there any .Net Maui C# code example that does this?

Thanks for your response, Liqun, however, the link you provided does not seem to indicate that my issue is fixed. It looks like I must handle cookies manually, as I stated above, unless I am missing something.

This might help, Xamarin WKWebView and Cookies.
